# Cocoapods documentation DSL directive of the podspec format has been deprecated

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I'm using pod install on a project which uses BlocksKit.  At the "Integrating client project" stage I get this message and the install stops:

"[BlocksKit (1.5.0)] The `documentation` DSL directive of the podspec format has been deprecated."

I've had quite a hunt around and can't find any information on what this specifically means and how I can get round it. I've also tried not using cocoapods and using the library directly but unfortunately haven't been able to do this either as the BlocksKit install documentation recommends cocoapods and the step by step appears to be somewhat out of date.  Can anyone offer any advice on how I might resolve the problem as I'm well and truly stuck.

Here's the full install text:

Successfully installed cocoapods-0.26.2

1 gem installed

Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-0.26.2...

Installing RDoc documentation for cocoapods-0.26.2...

Adams-Mac-mini:Project Adam$ pod install

[DEPRECATED] `dependency' is deprecated (use`pod')

[DEPRECATED] `dependency' is deprecated (use`pod')

Analyzing dependencies

Downloading dependencies

Using A2DynamicDelegate (2.0.2)

Using BlocksKit (1.5.0)

Using Reachability (3.0.0)

Using libffi (3.0.13)

Generating Pods project

Integrating client project

[!] [BlocksKit (1.5.0)] The `documentation` DSL directive of the podspec format has been deprecated.

Adams-Mac-mini:Project Adam$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning you're seeing in BlocksKit is caused by this portion of the current spec https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/BlocksKit/1.5.0/BlocksKit.podspec#L14-L22

Since it includes the `documentation` key which has, as the warning says, been deprecated. If you would like to fix this issue, you can fork the [specs repository](http://github.com/cocoapods/specs) make the change (remove that block of code) and submit it as a pull request.

As for the other deprecation message you're getting `'dependency' is deprecated (use pod')'`, in your Podfile you should be using `pod 'BlocksKit', '~> 1.5.0'` for each library you want to included. The documentation for that is [here](http://docs.cocoapods.org/podfile.html#pod)

Comment: Thanks Keith, as you used the word "warning" you're seeing, are you saying this isn't actually causing the install to fail?  I'm under the impression it is an error causing the install to stop as the start of the line has an exclamation mark and nothing is reported as happening after it?

Comment: Nope, that shouldn't cause any install to fail. Deprecations like that are just warnings that are printed after the install should be finished. Also based on that output in your question it looks like the install was successful.